# Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\....\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I am trying to publish a simple project in android studio .so i go to menu>build>build apk .but i get this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\ehsan\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format
```

I am so new in android studio

[image]

Comment: clean your project. and run it. not build apk.

Comment: @HaniyehKhaksar i don't have any device to simulate that in my local pc ,

Comment: you can connect your device. but if you want to do it, instead of build apk, use from Generate signed APK.

Comment: Hey, how did you solve this issue? even am facing same problem...

Answer (score 2):

I'm also facing same issue. for mine getting this type of issue, when I run app with my physical device.

**Solution**
Delete `.android` (path:C:\Users{your pc name}) folder in your work space then try with step by step process.

good luck

Comment: If this is the solution but when updating it gives errors in other libraries that are used in the old grandle example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131564/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-org-jetbrains-kotlin-gradle-internal-kaptexec

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced with the above error. While I was doing some research, I saw the issue usually comes about when a project is opened with a lower jdk than the one used in or during project creation. In my case, I had Jdk 8 setup as the project's gradle java version.
Updating the jdk to 11 solved it for me.
To do this, go to **File** -> **Project Structure** -> **Gradle Settings** -> **Gradle JDK** -> If you do not have Java 11, **Download JDK**, select 11 and download to set it up. Then retry executing the project