# SQLite Select Query returning null

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

**Following SQLite query (with room database library) returning null result.** Which is incorrect, as you can see in the attached image.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM REPOSITORY_DATABASE_TABLE WHERE item_category LIKE :key")
fun getItemByCategory(key: String) : LiveData<List<Item>>?

@Query("SELECT * FROM REPOSITORY_DATABASE_TABLE WHERE item_storage_type = :key ORDER BY item_name")
fun getItemByCategories(key: String) : LiveData<List<Item>>?
```

**where other queries as follow returning correct result in running application as well as in Android Debug Database**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM REPOSITORY_DATABASE_TABLE ORDER BY item_name")
fun getAllItems() : LiveData<List<Item>>
```

Item Data structure:

```
@Entity(tableName = ApplicationConstants.REPOSITORY_DATABASE_TABLE_NAME)
data class Item(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) @SerializedName("item_id")
var itemID: Long = 0L,

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_guid") @SerializedName("item_guid")
var itemGUID: String = "0",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_name") @SerializedName("item_name")
var itemName: String = "Mango",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_category") @SerializedName("item_category")
var itemCategory: String = "Fruit",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_weight") @SerializedName("item_weight")
var itemWeight: Int = 0,

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_count") @SerializedName("item_count")
var itemCount: Int = 1,

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_image") @SerializedName("item_image")
var itemImage: String = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131564/a-failure-occurred-while- 
executing-org-jetbrains-kotlin-gradle-internal-kaptexec",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_notes") @SerializedName("item_notes")
var itemNotes: String = "Sweet Yellow Mango",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_display_quantity") @SerializedName("item_display_quantity")
var itemDisplayQuantity: String = "0",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_storage_type") @SerializedName("item_storage_type")
var itemStorageType: String = "0",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_creation_date") @SerializedName("item_creation_date")
var itemCreationDate: String = "0",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_is_checked") @SerializedName("item_is_checked")
var itemIsChecked: String = "0",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_local_status") @SerializedName("item_local_status")
var itemLocalStatus: String = "0",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_last_added") @SerializedName("item_last_added")
var itemLastAdded: String = "0",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_notification_status") @SerializedName("item_notification_status")
var itemNotificationStatus: String = "0",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_priority") @SerializedName("item_priority")
var itemPriority: String = "0",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_notification_days") @SerializedName("item_notification_days")
var itemNotificationDays: Int = 1,

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_expiry") @SerializedName("item_expiry")
var itemExpiry: String = "0",

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_synonyms") @SerializedName("item_synonyms")
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
var itemSynonyms: List<String> = listOf("0","0")
)
```

Also while debugging the database with Android Debug Database I am getting correct response as shown in following image

[Android Debug Database Screenshot showing correct response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ioPj.png)

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the null safety operator from the return type of the query like this:

```
fun getItemByCategory(key: String) : LiveData<List<Item>>
```

And you don't have to use `@SerializedName()` if the SerializedName name is going to be the same as the variable itself.

And also it is very recommended if you use `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = True)` instead of `false`. Otherwise, you have to manually update the `PrimaryKey` every time you modify your table.

Comment: I removed null safety operator and ran the code but still seeing no change, getting null result only. Not sure why these queries not returning any values.


I'll definitely consider your suggestions.