# Android Build shows No error message Error on using @Query method in DAO

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-hilt

In my DAO associated to the room injected by Hilt into a ViewModel and is carrying a data class entity
"FoodMenu" which contains an array of objects which inturn use a type converter shows error on using @Query but works fine with @Insert or @Delete.

**My Dao**

```
@Dao
interface MenuDAO {


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun addMenu(element:FoodMenu):Unit
//If i comment out the below @Query..... section. There is no error

    @Query("SELECT * FROM menu")
    fun getMenu():List<FoodMenu>
    



}
```

**AppDatabase**

```
@Database (entities=[Cart::class,FoodMenu::class],version = 1,exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(TypeConverter::class)

abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun menuDAO():MenuDAO





}
```

**Data Class and type converter**

```
data class Food(
    var name:String,
    var price:Int,
    var image:String,

)

@Entity(tableName="menu")
data class FoodMenu(
    @PrimaryKey
    var category:String,

    var list:List<Food>

)

class TypeConverter{
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromFoodList(value:List<Food>?)= Gson().toJson(value)
    @TypeConverter
    fun toFoodList(value:String)= Gson().fromJson(value,Array<Food>::class.java).toList()




}
```

**MY ERROR**

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press parent Build section when error occurs it shows cause of the error as explained in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131564/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-org-jetbrains-kotlin-gradle-internal-kaptexec)