# Cannot compile since updating kotlin to 1.6.10 & room 2.4.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-room

I'm getting an error since I upgraded to Kotlin 1.6.10 and room to 2.4.0. The error is unclear tho, so I don't really know where to start looking.

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.

I'm guessing there's something incompatible in my entities, but when downgrading everything works flawlessly. My question is: how can I detect what is wrong? For me the errors are quite vague.

When I run gradlew --scan it says my JVM is still 1.8, but I've updated everywhere to 11.

**EDIT**:
I've managed to force my Gradle using 11 by changing the org.gradle.java.home property. Now it's giving me the following error:

```
 A failure occurred while executing
 org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
  (No message provided)
    (No message provided)
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: <nulltype> cannot be represented as a Class<?>.
       <nulltype> cannot be represented as a Class<?>.
```

**EDIT2**:

I've read in another StackOverflow thread that I should update AS to the latest patch which I did. Unfortunately, this didn't help.

**EDIT3**:

It seems like the room version (2.4.1) is also part of the problem. When downgrading everything but room it is still an error. If I try to run with kotlin 1.5.31, room 2.3.0 & compose 1.0.5 it runs fine.

**EDIT4**:

After upgrading to room 2.4.2 and also adding KSP I get the following error instead:

```
[ksp] [MissingType]: Element 'be.tradecom.kraken.objects.parts.Part' references a type that is not present - be.tradecom.kraken.objects.parts.Part
```

When searching for this error I only get 1 result of someone who had the same problem and fixed it by upgrading to Kotlin 1.6.0. I tried downgrading from 1.6.10 to 1.6.0, but compose 1.1.0 needs 1.6.10.

I removed big parts of the first error because I reached the character limit and I don't think it matters anymore.

Comment: Are you using annotationProcessor Dependency in gradle??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131564/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-org-jetbrains-kotlin-gradle-internal-kaptexec 
You may find this helpful.

Comment: This has helped me get rid of the 1.8 error in --scan. Now I get this result: https://scans.gradle.com/s/aa5y7o2dtps62

Comment: Kind of same issue with v2.5.0-alpha02 of Room, kotlin v1.6.21, and jetpack compose 1.2.0-beta03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've had to work on this project again after a year.

I've discovered that the `[MissingType]` errors were only occurring in entities that had `SerializedName` annotations. My project is set up with multiple modules and `com.google.code.gson:gson` was not imported into the module containing the database entity.

After finally adding it to that build.grade the project would compile again.

Comment: Good catch! For me I had gson imported in a parent module. Changin that import to `api` does the trick. Well done!

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this error by the following steps:

1- ensure that Gradle JDK is set to "Embedded JDK version 11.0.12/snap/android-studio/121/android-studio/jre"

2- Invalidate Caches - check both options are ticked, including "Clear filsystem cache and local history" then "Invalidate and Restart"

3-  In AD menu go to File -> Project Structure -> on left hand menu select "Suggestions" and upgrade all components listed there.

4- changed compileSdk 31 to compileSdk 32

I also found this post helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62919508/17650331

Comment: Have you also upgraded your Kotlin to 1.7.0? If I keep it up to date with the latest compatible with Compose I still get the same error. If I go above and ignore it I get a userIR error (which is caused by incompatibility if I understand it correctly)

Comment: Yes, upgraded to Kotlin 1.7.0, however my project is not using Compose

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't work for me. I had to downgrade from Kotlin 1.7 to Kotlin 1.6.21 to make my sources compile.