A failure occurred while update to kotlin 1.8.0 from 1.4.32
I have an error that I have been trying to resolve for 3 days and it has me blocked, since I do not receive many lights of the error as such.
My project consist of:
Gradle Version 7.1.2
Kotlin Version 1.4.32
JDK Version 11.0.24
compileSdkVersion 34
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 34
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1
Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11709847, built on April 12, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.15.0-121-generic

The thing is that I need to implement the In-App Updates library:
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0'
This forces me to upgrade the Kotlin version to 1.8.0
When I upload the version I get the following error:
The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
This error consists of deleting extensions from the project, I do this as indicated.
After doing this I get the error that I have not been able to move forward with.:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDevelopKotlin'.

A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Cuando lo ejecuto con --stacktrace:
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0
Any help is valuable to me right now, thanks in advance!
I hope the project runs normally and I don't get the mentioned error.

Please update the error logs with proper formatting.
I think your problem might be related to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131564/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-org-jetbrains-kotlin-gradle-internal-kaptexec?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top

This question is similar to: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
