# com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, gradle

I'm new tho android please help me to fix this issue.
when I debug apk with **generate signed apk** option. it will generate **debug.apk** successfully. I'm getting issue when I **run** project with my **physical device** (mobile phone) via USB cable.

**build output**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\91949.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

**My pc**

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart, com.thoughtworks.gauge, io.flutter, org.intellij.plugins.markdown

Comment: For anyone interested, FYI. [Possible Related Unsolved Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674385/failed-to-read-key-androiddebugkey-from-store-c-users-android-debug-keys)